# Integration in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I've recently started working with Isabelle and I've been trying to explore different parts of it. Is it  possible to prove an integration possible in Isabelle? Such as the integrating x between [0,1], dx. If possible, please could you direct me to the relevant Isabelle .thy file, or even a brief tutorial.

I've tried looking around but no success.

Thank you.

Comment: I would reformulate your question as not everyone is well versed with publication of scientific documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant theories are in [`HOL-Multivariate_Analysis`](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL-Multivariate_Analysis/index.html), in particular theory `Integration` and following.

Disclaimer: I have not worked with these definition at all, just know about their existence.

Answer (score 3):

There is also `IntervalIntegral.thy` from https://github.com/avigad/isabelle/blob/master/Analysis/Interval_Integral.thy. This has the advantage of a rich measure-theoretic background and will be merged into Isabelle's measure theory library soon. If you want to prove that the integral from somewhere to somewhere equals some term, you usually use the fundamental theorem of calculus (`interval_integral_FTC_finite`) to prove that you have an indefinite integral and then use that to compute the definite integral. Integration by substitution is also available, e.g. `interval_integral_substitution_finite`.